# When I rotate my gameObject, it starts moving in the wrong direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging

I'm practicing my unity programming by creating a top-down shooter, like the "Journey of the Prairie King" from Stardew Valley. When I look up/down and shoot, I'm trying to rotate the bullet 90 degrees so that it is facing the correct direction that it is moving in. However, whenever I rotate the bullet, it goes left when I'm facing up, and right when I'm facing down. Without any rotation, it moves just fine. Here is my code:

```
public class BulletMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 moveDirection;
    private GameObject player;
    public int speed;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("Player");
        Move();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        CheckIfOutOfBounds();
    }
    
    //Moves the bullet in the direction the player is facing when the bullet is fired
    private void Move()
    {
        if (player.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().GetPlayerFacing().Equals("up"))
        {
            RotateBullet(90);
            moveDirection = new Vector2(0, 1);
        }
        if (player.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().GetPlayerFacing().Equals("down"))
        {
            RotateBullet(90);
            moveDirection = new Vector2(0, -1);
        }
        if (player.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().GetPlayerFacing().Equals("left"))
        {
            //Moves the bullet in front of the gun
            transform.Translate(-0.363f, 0, 0);
            moveDirection = new Vector2(-1, 0);
        }
        if (player.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().GetPlayerFacing().Equals("right"))
        {
            //Moves the bullet in front of the gun
            transform.Translate(0.363f, 0, 0);
            
            moveDirection = new Vector2(1, 0);
        }
    }

    //Destroys the bullet if it goes off-screen
    private void CheckIfOutOfBounds()
    {
        if (transform.position.x is > 10 or < -10)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

        if (transform.position.y is > 10 or < -10)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void RotateBullet(int degrees)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, degrees));
    }
}
```

Tried:

transform.Rotate(Vector3(0, 0, 90))
transform.Rotate(Vector3.right))
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, degrees)); ---> currently using

Comment: it seems odd you manually control bullets

Answer (score 0):

As BugFinder mentioned this is a little unorthodox and has more steps than needed but.

```cs
// move dir should always be on x if you're also rotating.
if (player.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().GetPlayerFacing().Equals("up"))
{
    RotateBullet(90);
    moveDirection = new Vector2(1, 0);
}
if (player.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().GetPlayerFacing().Equals("down"))
{
    RotateBullet(90);
    moveDirection = new Vector2(-1, 0);
}
```

Here's how you can test this in real life:
look at your monitor and sidestep to the left.
that's `moveDirection = new Vector2(-1, 0);`

now look at your monitor, turn your body 90 degrees to the left, and walk forward.

that's `RotateBullet(90);` with `moveDirection = new Vector2(0,1);`

different, but the same.

Hope this helps

EDIT:

I also recommend setting player where in the script that instantiates the bullet instead of by using a gameobject.find() in the bullet script and changing player to be of type PlayerMovement instead of GameObject so you're not calling getcomponent a lot.

You're not going to have to worry about performance for this project but it builds good habits to never ever use gameobject.find()

EDIT 2 (Regarding comment):

So in your playerscript where the player shoots and you spawn a bullet I assume you're doing something like `Instantiate(bulletPrefab,...);`

You could do:

```
GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab,...);
bullet.GetComponent<YourBulletScript>().player = this;

// remember to change GameObject player to PlayerMovement player
// in your bullet script!
```

You could also set more things instead of calling back to the player, for example you could set movedirection here instead of using GetPlayerFacing, then you don't even need a reference to the player.

For my solutions I usually have it so the bullet script just handles it's own movement and what it bumps into. I instantiate it, give it a direction, and it's on its own.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have another question that relates to what you brought up, though. By "setting player where in the script that instantiates the bullet instead of by using a gameobject.find()," how exactly should I properly go about doing this, format wise?

Comment: @Aguywithquestions I updated the answer to provide more context.